# Run and terminate a program (Python under Windows)

Tags: python, windows, autorun

I'd like to create a small script that basically does this:

```
run program1.exe --> kill program1.exe 
after n seconds --> run program1.exe again.
```

I know some basic Python and would read up on this, but I'm in a bit of a hurry and just need this to get done ASAP.

If someone has a script/idea or could help my out with just the syntax I need to open and kill the .exe file, please... I don't mind solutions in other languages either. I'm sorry if this is a bit "please write my code"-ish, that's not something I typically do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read up on the [subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

```
import subprocess, time
p = subprocess.Popen(['program1.exe'])
time.sleep(1) # Parameter is in seconds
p.terminate()
p.wait()
```